# getObject from S3 bucket and display in browser using AWS SSO and Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, browser, single-sign-on, aws-sdk

I've been looking everywhere and can't seem to find an example that comes close. This is as close as I've gotten:

```
import {APIGatewayProxyEvent} from 'aws-lambda';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const creds = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'dev'});
const S3 = new AWS.S3(creds);

import {Readable} from "stream";

export const handler = async (_event: APIGatewayProxyEvent):  Promise<Readable> => {

    const s3Params = {
        Bucket: "some-aws-s3-buckeet",
        Key: "some-folder/some-document.pdf"
    }

    return S3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream();
}
```

After this, I'm getting the error:

`InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

I've logged into AWS using the following:

`aws sso login --profile dev`